# store different objects

Tags: java

I want to create different classes and they should be all stored in one ArrayList.
If i use:

```
interface ProgramInterface { 
   void someMethods();
}

public abstract class CustomProgram implements ProgramInterface { 
   // stuff
}
```

Then i can make my own class like

```
class P_randomBars extends CustomProgram {
```

What i like about this is that the methods from the interface show up in the javadoc and from CustomProgram in the same page (CustomProgram).

But then i can't store them in one array (or i have to store them as object which i don't want).

Another way is:

```
public interface CustomProgram {
   void someMethods();
}

public abstract class ProgramBase {
  // stuff
}
```

And then i create a classes like:

```
class P_randomBars extends ProgramBase implements CustomProgram{
```

What i like is that i can store classes i make like that in a ArrayList. Like:
`ArrayList<CustomProgram> programs = new ArrayList<CustomProgram>();`

But in the javadoc the abstract class and the interface are not connected which make's unclear for the user that he has to extend and then implement.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3062697/32090 explaining the usage of `@Inheritdoc`

Comment: "But then i can't store them in one array (or i have to store them as object which i don't want)." Can you  explain what do you mean by that?

Comment: If all your classes must extend the abstract class, then you need not interface at all.